# Chrome Extension Manifest V3 not working with Google Picker API

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, google-drive-picker

Google Chrome Extension Manifest v3 does not allow external scripts & inline scripts:

> In Manifest V3, all of your extension's logic must be included in the extension. You can no longer load and execute a remotely hosted file.
> ― [source](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/mv3-migration/#remotely-hosted-code)

This is my `content_security_policy` in `manifest.json`:

```json
"content_security_policy": {
        "extension_pages": "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval';  style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'self' 'unsafe-inline';",
        "sandbox": "sandbox"
}
```

I've been trying to use the **Google** [Drive Picker API](https://developers.google.com/drive/picker/guides/overview) inside of a **Google** Chrome extension, but somehow fail to do so.

The library requires these two scripts:

```html
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="onApiLoad()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
```

Which I have downloaded locally inside the extension:

```html
<script async defer src="./lib/apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script async defer src="./lib/accounts.google.com/gsi/client.js"></script>
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => gapiLoaded())
```

But then these two scripts at their turn install other external scripts which is not allowed in Manifest v3:

- [Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUSsc.png)
- [Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9sg8.png)

I tried both in a popup and in a tab created with:

```js
chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.runtime.getURL('setup.html')})
```

Both give the same error

How can I use the **Google** Drive Picker API inside of a **Google** Chrome extension?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `https://apis.google.com/js/api.js` and 
`https://accounts.google.com/` in content_security_policy

```
"content_security_policy": {
"extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
"sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'https://apis.google.com/' 'https://accounts.google.com/'  'https://www.googleapis.com' 'https://ajax.googleapis.com'; object-src 'self'"
},
```

Comment: The urls in script-src work without the quotes around them: https://content-security-policy.com/script-src/ I think the quotes around is invalid actually. But even with this sandbox rule, and my html page set in the sandbox.pages section of the manifest, I get a warning for each url: 

'content_security_policy.sandbox': Ignored insecure CSP value "https://apis.google.com/" in directive 'script-src'.
... ref: https://i.imgur.com/UM3JRM5.png

This is strange because there is also an url in the official documentation example: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/sandbox/